# How to move to existing viewcontroller from another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

When I start the app my initial view is `MainViewController`.
Then on button click I move to `AnotherViewController`.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("myFirstSegue", sender: self)
```

On `AnotherViewController` I have a button that should return me back to `MainViewController` but I don't want to instantiate new but to use existing instance.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var story = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as! ViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: story)
self.showViewController(navigationController, sender: nil)
```

With this code I create new so I lost data that I stored on that view.

How can I get existing instance and just move to it?

**UPDATE**

To explain issue better if on first view I have `UISwitch` and move to another `ViewController` and then get back to first I want to `UISwitch` stay same not "reset".

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a navigation controller, doing this will pop to your previous controller. `navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`

Comment: No. I don't use navigation controller. I want to make same effect like you change tabs on TabBarController.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigation controller maintains the stack of viewcontrollers. just pop your viewcontroller and you will be back to your previous view controller.

```
navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

or use unwind segue from storyboard.

[What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)